2007 Ford F150 have preprogrammed plug n play with keys but truck won't start. Is there steps to start it besides plug in and start?
Bought Ecu pcm plug n play is preprogrammed and came with keys which I had cut to old key. But truck will not start. What steps do I need to figure why won't start
